# Firebase TestLab on IOS - the .xctestrun file didn't specify any test targets

Tags: ios, firebase, unit-testing, firebase-test-lab

I'm trying to use firebase TestLab on iOS using this guide:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/ios/firebase-console#build_xctests_for_your_app

but after I upload the zip file including the xctestrun file I'm getting the following error:

```
Upload invalid: the .xctestrun file didn't specify any test targets.
```

I have two targets in my app and a Tests target and a UI tests target,
On both test target, I set the Target I want to test as the host application.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the xctestrun file? Is it not empty? The best way to get help with this issue is to join the [Firebase Community](https://firebase.community/) and post this question along with your test matrix ID in the #test-lab channel on Slack. Someone from the Test Lab team will help you out.

Comment: What could have happened that while building you only built your app target, but not your test targets. In that case the .xctestrun file would be empty.

Answer (score 7):

In my case the following order of actions helped:

1. open your app's `.xcworkspace` file
2. go to `File -> New -> Target`
3. choose `iOS Unit Testing Bundle` and press the button Next
4. check the credentials like Product Name, Team, Bundle Identifier, etc. and then press the button Finish

Now you need to make a new attempt to build for testing `(Product -> Build For -> Testing)` and follow the Firebase instruction regarding creating an archive

Answer (score 1):

This probably happened because you testing targets are not part of the scheme when building.

Take a look at the .xctestrun and see if it is an empty .plist file. If it's empty then add the testing targets when building.